# What are all the Codr Codes?

Tags: not-tonight

In not tonight it's possible to enter codes into the Codr app. What are all the potential codes and what do they unlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the codes and what they unlock:

- **421351** Unlocks the Skelly Outfit in ShopR.
- **511111** Unlocks the Grim Reaper Outfit in ShopR
- **871234** Unlocks the Day of the Dead Skeleton

The codes can be found in the [news updates section](https://store.steampowered.com/news/?appids=733790) on Steam.